# Convert string into float in C++ with full Significant figures [Fixed working in Dev C++]

Tags: c++, string, casting, type-conversion, double

> I want to convert the String which contains numerical Float into Float or Double Data type values with full significant figures Please help me to fix this

```
#include <sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string q = "23.3453535";
float f;
istringstream(q) >>f;
f=1.0*f;   // stack-overflow viewer it is an example because i want to process this float value 
cout<<f;
}

/*OutPut is:
23.3454
but i want this 
23.3453535
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control the precision then include `#include <iomanip>` and use `std::cout << std::setprecision(17);` to set the number of digits you want. Also float has 6 significant bits precision whereas double has 12. So whenever your string has more than 6 digits in decimal there is a possibility of loosing the precision.

Comment: Sir i want Another thing Octal into String like : 110145154154157040127157162154144 in Hello World ( Picture is attached )http://i.stack.imgur.com/wXWyi.jpg

Comment: @UmairSajidMinhas:- You need to ask a seperate question for that. Also do share your efforts in that!

Comment: @UmairSajidMinhas:- For this one I can give you the answer, `res= std::to_string( std::stoi( yourOctal, 0, 8 ) );
}`

Comment: but stoi is not working in DEV C++ compiler what is your suggestion  i should change compiler or you will give me another code for dev c++ ?

Comment: @UmairSajidMinhas:- Dev C++. I am not even sure I have worked on it :(

Comment: Oh so any header file for stoi ??

Comment: @UmairSajidMinhas:- Its in `#include <string>` only

Answer (score 0):

There are TWO issues here:

1. You are running into the default formatting of floating point output on `std::ostream`, which is 6 digits. Use `std::setprecision(n)` to increase the precision to cover enough decimal places as you wish.
2. You are trying to get more precision out of a `float` than it will support. `"23.3453535"` is 9 digits long, so with 3.3 digits per digit it is approximately 30 bits are needed to store this number with all bits preserved. (exactly, you need `ceil(log(233453535)/log(2))` which is 28). A `float` only has 23 bits to store the mantissa, so whilst the value is in the representable range, some of the last digits will disappear. You can fix this by using `double` instead of `float` - but as `float`, you will not ever get 9 valid decimal digits.

Comment: yeah so i will change float by double but now what is the code of Converting string into double ?

Comment: `stringstream >> var` should do the trick, what about that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks your answer also help me :)